# Infinite series of a rational function

Tags: sequences-and-series

According to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4+4a^4}=\frac{1+a\pi\coth(a\pi)}{8a^4}$$

If we take $a=\frac{1}{2}$, then

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4+\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1+\frac{\pi}{2}\coth\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{\frac{1}{2}}\approx5.425$$

But wolframalpha tells another answer: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F%28n%5E4%2B1%2F4%29%2C+n%3D0..oo

What is the correct closed formula?

Comment: Maybe $a$ should be integer

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: no, that's irrelevant. But the sums should be on $n\geq 0$, not $i\geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Poisson summation formula, for any $c\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ we have
$$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{n^2+c^2} = \frac{\pi}{c}\coth(\pi c) \tag{1}$$
so, by symmetry,
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n^2+c^2}=\frac{1}{2c^2}+\frac{\pi}{2c}\coth(\pi c).\tag{2} $$
Similarly
$$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{n^4+4a^4}=\frac{\pi}{4a^3}\cdot\frac{\sinh(2\pi a)+\sin(2\pi a)}{\cosh(2\pi a)-\cos(2\pi a)}\tag{3} $$
leads to
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n^4+\frac{1}{4}}= \frac{2+\pi  \sinh (\pi )+2 \cosh (\pi )}{1+\cosh (\pi )}=2+\pi\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}\approx 4.88132.\tag{4}$$
I have fixed the formula on Wikipedia.